# Cannot post entry to facebook fan page wall as an admin

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying in vain to post to a Facebook fan page wall as admin. I want to post new entries with pictures, link, description etc on my fan page wall. This is integrated into my custom cms so that whenever a story is updated on my website, it automatically posts the same on the fan page wall.
The problem is that whenever I post, the post does not appear as posted by admin. It appears as posts by others on the right side of the timeline.
How do I go around the following code so that it posts as admin on my fan page wall? I been looking at it for two days, checked similar stuff on the web and so, but I still cant seem to crack it. Help will be appreciated.

```
$page_id = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$article_link = "http://xyz.com/articles/headlines/title-one/";

$result = $facebook->api("/me/accounts");
foreach($result["data"] as $page) {
    if($page["id"] == $page_id) {
        $page_access_token = $page["access_token"];
        break;
    }
}   

$og_title = "Sample title";
$og_image = "http://xyz.com/images/articles/919161344090182.jpg";
$msg = "some description of the article";
$feed_array = array(
    'access_token' => "$page_access_token",
    'message' => "$msg",
    'picture' => "$og_image",
    'link' => "$article_link",
    'name' => "$og_title",
    'caption' => "$og_title"
);

try {
    $page_post = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$feed_array);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
}
```

Comment: You should be getting back exceptions from the `$facebook->api()` call on errors. Does they thrown? If yes, what's the message of them?

Comment: Sorry for the oversight. I will slot the error catching in. I am not getting any errors. The problem is that the post is not appearing as posted by admin, but as posted by others. I need it to post as admin.

Comment: Sounds like your access_token is not really page access token (i see the variable name) or the user who was used to create the token is not allowed to post on the page. There [have been changes a few days ago](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/07/23/new-marketing-tools-for-pages/) around pages, but i don't know if it's related.

Comment: Is your $page_access_token actually a _page_ access token? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens And is this what you actually want, to make the post appear as to be post “by” the page itself, or what do you mean when you say “by admin”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **post as the page** - that means that the post will appear as if the page posted an update [as it appears here :

[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HnYQ.png)

Then you will have to use a valid page access token.  There is information on how to obtain this kind of token in the [Facebook Authentication Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).  It looks like you already have a token in your code - you can test it using the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and see if it is still valid.

Another thing you may want to try, instead of appending the token to be one of the parameters of the post array, you could use the `setAccessToken()` function of the PHP SDK.  More details can be found here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-setAccessToken/

```
$facebook->setAccessToken($new_access_token);
```

---

As a final BTW note, when you specify elements of an array, unless you are wanting to specifically add the quote character, there is no need to wrap the values in quotes.

```
$feed_array = array(
  'access_token' => $page_access_token,
  'message' => $msg,
  'picture' => $og_image,
  ...
);
```

If you want to explicitly add quotes to the values you would have to do something like this -

```
$feed_array = array(
  'string_value' => '"'.$value.'"',
  ...
);
```

Comment: Thnx for the corrections guys. Sorry what I meant was I want my CMS to post as the page, not admin. I checked the page access token and found that it had expired, so i generated a new one, from graph api explorer http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ . Even with this new token, the updates still appear as before (not posted by page). Is there something else that am missing?

Comment: using the correct token will get you the results you want.   how did you obtain the token you are using? did you get the `manage_pages` permission from an admin?

Comment: I came across this. If i remove all other params and leave the message param only, it posts just fine (as the page)! But the moment i introduce the other parameters, it posts differently (as a regular user)! How come?

Comment: Lix, I generated the token form graph api explorer. The token is valid. I also have the manage_pages permisions granted.

Comment: tokens are per application, you need **your application** to generate the token.